# Devise doesn't override email views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have my scope views reset_password_instructions.html

and in my devise.rb

```
  config.scoped_views = true
```

It works fine in development and sends the custom email. However, in production, when user receives email, device sent a default template.

How can I fix this in production?

Answer (score 0):

when I use devise I this is what I do to send my own emails

```
class MyMailer < Devise::Mailer   
  helper :application # gives access to all helpers defined within `application_helper`.
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers # Optional. eg. `confirmation_url`
  default template_path: 'devise/mailer' # to make sure that your mailer uses the devise views
end
```

now, in your `config/initializers/devise.rb`, you can set `config.mailer` to `"MyMailer"`.

You may now use your MyMailer in the same way as any other mailer. In case you want to override specific mails to add extra headers, you can do so by simply overriding the method and calling super at the end of your custom method, to trigger Devise's default behavior.

You can also override any of the basic headers (from, reply_to, etc) by manually setting the options hash:

```
def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
  headers["Custom-header"] = "Bar"
  opts[:from] = 'my_custom_from@example.com'
  opts[:reply_to] = 'my_custom_from@example.com'
  super
end
```

In order to get preview (if User is your devise model name):

```
# test/mailers/previews/my_mailer_preview.rb
# Preview all emails at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/my_mailer

class MyMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview

  def confirmation_instructions
    MyMailer.confirmation_instructions(User.first, "faketoken", {})
  end

  def reset_password_instructions
    MyMailer.reset_password_instructions(User.first, "faketoken", {})
  end

  def unlock_instructions
    MyMailer.unlock_instructions(User.first, "faketoken", {})
  end
end
```

I hope that this was useful :)

Comment: devise only sent a defualt mail in production